# Bluetooth connection between an Android phone and EV3 brick?

Tags: ev3, bluetooth

I've paired my phone to the brick, however I was wondering if there were any resources out there regarding a simple android app to type something out on my phone and output it on the robots LCD screen. I am new to the scene and I have not found any resources for it.

Answer (score 1):

[MIT App Inventor](https://appinventor.mit.edu/) is a popular way to make simple Android apps that can communicate with an EV3. It has [special blocks just for EV3](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/legomindstorms.html).